# Inner Join on 2 tables(both on different Servers)

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do an inner join on 2 tables where both the tables are on different server??

Comment: Are you sure this should be C#, and not some Database question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [linked server (B)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to server A then write the following query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [SERVERB].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] A
    INNER JOIN [SERVERA].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible in SQL code. How you would do it in C# I don't know but in SQl Server, I would set up linked servers and then the code is:

```
select t1.field1, t2.field2
From server1.database1.dbo.table1 t1
join server2.database2.dbo.table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
```

So you just use the four part name instead of the three part name. But you do have to have a linked server set up first.

Answer (score 0):

You can download both tables to the client, then perform a join using LINQ.

For more detail, please provide more details.

Comment: That would cause some overhead where there are a lot of records

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server try using a Linked Server, if Oracle use a database link. I am not sure how it would be achieved in the rest.